# Erase partition and install Ubuntu on entire disk

Tags: upgrade, partitioning

I have 2 partitions (Windows and Ubuntu 13.04) and I am asked which one to boot each time I turn on my computer.

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 to the entire disk.

I do not mind if all previous Ubuntu/Win data are lost.

How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at [Installing Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall).

Comment: Boot into  ubuntu, format your  Windows partition and update your grub   using command `sudo update-grub`  or have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows)

Comment: If you still have priblems, or don't know how to do something, please feel free to leave your skype, facebook etc. in comment, and I'll help you

Answer (score 1):

Like @user251046 said,

A "clean" installation is the way to go... It's easier, will give you a "clean" system and allow you to encrypt your entire drive, including that which was formerly used by Microsoft Windows.

Download a copy of the disk image (ending in ".iso") here (Most computers made in the last 3-5 years are 64-bit compatible, so select that option unless you're using something particularly old...):
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Then burn it to a DVD:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Or create a "thumb" drive:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Once you're good to go, simply plug-in your "thumb" drive/insert your DVD and reboot your computer...

Near the start of the installation, it will ask you if you want to wipe your computer and start afresh - select that and follow the bouncing ball.

If you get stuck, there's some helpful instructions (with screenshots) here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest